# Push Notification in status bar Android Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, notifications, push

I have this code in "index.js" file. 
Communication takes place , show me thenotification , but how can I do to display the notification in the status bar when the app is closed ? Thanks for the help.

var pushNotification;

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
    {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

        if( $("#home").length > 0)
        {
            // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
            //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
            e.preventDefault();
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else
        {
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        }
    }, false);

    try 
    { 
        pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' || device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {
                pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"615604299101","ecb":"onNotification"});        // required!
        } else {
            pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
        }
    }
    catch(err) 
    { 
        txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
        txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
        alert(txt); 
    } 
}

// handle GCM notifications for Android
function onNotification(e) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

    switch( e.event )
    {
        case 'registered':
        if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
            // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
            console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
        }
        break;

        case 'message':
            // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
            // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
            if (e.foreground)
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                    // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
                        // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                        var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                        // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                        // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                        var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);

                my_media.play();
            }
            else
            {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                if (e.coldstart)
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                else
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
            }

            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
            //android only
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
            //amazon-fireos only
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
        break;

        case 'error':
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
        break;

        default:
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
        break;
    }
}

function tokenHandler (result) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
    // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
    // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
}

function successHandler (result) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
}

function errorHandler (error) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should appear with this code. Are you sending the notification with `message` and `title`? If they are missing, the notification doesn't appears

Answer (score 0):

The notification shows in the status bar when the app is closed or inactive

```
 if (e.coldstart)
  // Your code when the user clicks on the notification.
 }
```

Comment: I thank you for answers but I would like to ask you a clarification . The code you passed me where I need to add ?

Comment: send me your email address so in my free time I can build a sample app that uses push notification and send you the source code

Comment: Or maybe I can just upload it to my [github repo](http://www.github.com/whebcraft)

Comment: Sure. My email is: francescocassano945@gmail.com
Many thanks for your help.